# React v16 – pass ref from child to parent through a wrapper component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, react-forwardref

I have an existing component hierarchy that looks like this:

```jsx
const Parent = props => {
  const divElement = useRef()
  // do something with divElement
  return <Child ref={divElement} {...some props} />
}

const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}><some stuff here></div>
}
```

This is all fine, but now I need to conditionally add a wrapper component, which wraps the `<Child>` component to add some special case props.

Basically what I want is something like this:

```jsx
const Parent = props => {
  const divElement = useRef()
  // do something with divElement
  return someCondition ? <Wrapper {...some props} /> : <Child ref={divElement} {...some props} />
}

const Wrapper = props => {
  return <Child {...different props} />
}

const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}><some stuff here></div>
}
```

I'm stuck on how to pass the `ref` from `Child` through the `Wrapper` back to `Parent`, so the `Parent` can access the `Child`'s `ref` no matter whether the `Wrapper` is there or not...

Comment: Wrap `Wrapper` component in `React.forwardRef()`. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-worker-mgl7f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using `React.forwardRef` like @Reductio said, you could use custom props to pass down the ref to the children whether with the Wrapper or not.

I learned this from here: https://deniapps.com/blog/clarify-react-ref-by-examples
Passing ref via custom props is much simpler. The code likes this:

```
const Parent = props => {
  const divElement = useRef()
  // do something with divElement
  return someCondition ? <Wrapper {...some props} forwardedRef={divElement} /> : <Child forwardedRef={divElement} {...some props} />
}

const Wrapper = props => {
  //MAKE SURE "different props" includes the custom props: forwardedRef from props
  return <Child {...different props} />
}

const Child =({forwardRef, ...rest}) => {
  return <div ref={forwardedRef} {...rest}><some stuff here></div>
}
```

Comment: This is of course a working solution. I would always prefer using forward refs, because it's just the normal way of handling refs in react and you have a fixed protocol how to pass refs. However, this is more like a guideline you can follow but you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass anything from child to parent. Of course you can use callbacks, but you wouldn't use them to pass refs or something similar.

You just should make the Wrapper also a ForwardRef:

```
const Wrapper = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <Child ref={ref} {...your other props} />
})
```

Now you can just call:

```
return someCondition ? <Wrapper ref={divElement} {...some props} /> : <Child ref={divElement} {...some props} />
```

and your ref will always be the div you want.